# How to define dependency in cdbcache in yii framework for php?

Tags: performance, caching, yii

I have enable the dbcache in php by addin this code in main.php file

```
 'cache'=>array(
            'class'=>'system.caching.CDbCache',
        'connectionID'=>'db',
        ),
```

Now I want to define dependancy for this cache for checking last updated record but i am unable to do this.

the query is:-

```
public function actionProductList()
    {
        $model=new Product();
        $main=array();
        /* $random =Product::model()->find(array(
        'select'=>'MAX(update_time)',
        ));
        $dependency =new CDbCacheDependency($random);
        var_dump($random);*/
        $productList1=Product::model()->cache(60)->with('productimages')->findAll();
        foreach($productList1 as $productList)
        {
            $main1=array();
            foreach($productList->productimages as $list)
            {
                if($list->isProfileImage==1)
                {
            $main1[]=array("path"=>$list->path,"imageId"=>$list->imageId);
            }
            }
            if($productList->isPublish==1)
            {
                $main[]=array("productId"=>$productList->productId,"productName"=>$productList->productName,
                                "brandId"=>$productList->brandId,"mrp"=>$productList->mrp,
                                "isTaxInclude"=>$productList->isTaxInclude,"isAvailable"=>$productList->isAvailable,
                                "isFreeDelivery"=>$productList->isFreeDelivery,"description"=>$productList->description,
                                "isPublish"=>$productList->isPublish,"publishDate"=>$productList->publishDate,
                                "isActive"=>$productList->isActive,"userId"=>$productList->userId,
                                "createDate"=>$productList->createDate,"ipAddress"=>$productList->ipAddress,
                                "offerPrice"=>$productList->offerPrice,"manufactureId"=>$productList->manufactureId,"proimage"=>$main1);
        }
        }   
            echo"{\"Product\":".CJSON::encode($main)."}";

    }
```

and i have no update_time field in product table so how i can achieve dependency for this query...

Comment: Without update timestamp it's pretty obviously impossible to track changes with an easy query. All you can do is to query `MAX(id)` in the dependency. But this would only trigger a change, if there was a new record added. Not if an existing one was modified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should explain what you have tried and what exactly you want to cache. There's also a basic example in the [manual](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/caching.data#query-caching):

```
$dependency = new CDbCacheDependency('SELECT MAX(update_time) FROM tbl_post');
$posts = Post::model()->cache(1000, $dependency)->findAll();
```

Comment: actually i want to define the dependancy for the query in which i fetch all data from two/three tables...but whenever if i update my tables then this dependency should catch data from the database...

Comment: Please update your question and add what you have tried so far. E.g. the query code.